# Android Studio Pre Dexing fails

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I'm trying to switch from Intellij Idea 12 to Android Studio 0.2.1
Currently my android project is setup with the maven-android-plugin. I use actionbarsherlock as an apklib dependency.

When I try to build the project with Android Studio it fails at the pre-dexing phase with

```
Error:Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":
Error:Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] when not building a core library.
Error:Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] going on.
```

However the only dependency to xpp3 is from actionbarsherlock and if you look into the project structure you see that it has scope "provided". So in my opinion this should not be pre-dexed or included into the apk at all.

Have you made similar observations? Or did you get an android-maven-project with actionbarsherlock dependency to build in android studio? Any hints on how to get this working with android studio are appreciated :)

Regards 
Frank

Comment: How are you adding the support libraries dependency to your project?

Comment: Using maven: `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        </dependency>`

Comment: You don't want to use android studios with gradle build system?

Comment: We'll possibly switch to gradle at a later time. So far we are quite happy with our maven build system.

Comment: Seeing a similar issues since switching to 0.2.1, wasn't an issue in 0.2 that i noticed.

Answer (score 11):

I have found the problem. It has nothing to do with android studio or with actionbar sherlock but with another apklib dependency that incorrectly declared to have dependencies to xpp3 and xmlParserApis with scope "compile" where it should be "provided".

Idea 12 had no problems with this but android studio/idea 13 preview seems to be more strict.

Just changing the scope to "provided" in the project structure solves the problem.

Comment: +1. Fixed the problem by changing the pom.xml of a dependency to "provided". Exclusions do not work.

Comment: Is there anything I can do if I can't change the pom of the dependency?

Comment: Some of my libraries are included from local jar files. And the xpp3 jar already included as "provided". After playing around it seems it needs to manually removed & re-import again as "provided" to make it work.

Comment: Ran into the same problem.. in case it helps anyone else, the culprit in my case was SlidingMenu

Comment: Frank dear - you're awesome! you've just saved me from hours of digging... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This structure worked for me in the end:

Copy ABS into project:

```
Project
├── build.gradle
├── Module
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── libs
│   └── src
├── libraries
│   └── ABS
│       ├── build.gradle
│       ├── libraries
│       ├── libs
│       └── src
└── settings.gradle
```

Project/settings.gradle:

```
include ':Module', ':libraries:ABS'
```

Project/libraries/ABS/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

Project/Module/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0"
    compile project(':libraries:ABS')
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the QName.class from the xpp3 jar.

Comment: Why are you downvoting my answer? It's the sanest thing todo, since xpp3.jar is totally broken in this respect. Alternatively go bug the xpp guys...